# Created by field shows claimbased username in page layout

Tags: page-layout

I created a new page layout. In this page layout I add the title, date and the author. For the author I add the field "Created by". Now I see this on the news article page:

i:0#.w|ntd1\mija

Is it possible I see the full name (Michael Jackson) ?

**UPDATE**

I try to show the column "Contact" and this is working fine. Why is the created by column showing something else?

Comment: What is the markup you used for placing the Author field on the page?

Comment: I am using now the column "Created By": <SharePointWebControls:TextField FieldName="4dd7e525-8d6b-4cb4-9d3e-44ee25f973eb" runat="server"></SharePointWebControls:TextField>

Answer (score 3):

In the Page Layout, you need to add the FormField with the Field Name `Author` in order to render the Display name.

```
<SharePoint:FormField ID="FormField1" ControlMode="Display" FieldName="Author" DisableInputFieldLabel="true" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Is it realy needed to add the author column? If it is also possible with the created by column I would like to use that column.

Comment: @KHA The Author property IS the Created By column :-)